# Convert X.509 Certificates from DER Encoding to PER Encoding

Tags: x509, asn.1

We need to transport an X.509 certificate via a QR code (or any 2D barcode, at this point, though not even PDF-417 seems to be able to store large enough amounts of data). At the moment, we write the certificate as a PEM encoding (which is a base64-encoded string representation of an X.509 certificate in DER format, plus opening and ending tags) into the QR code. The problem we face is that the resulting string is far too long.

While we could strip the opening and ending tags, this would not make much of a difference, which is why I took to the Interwebs to find a way to compress our certificate.

As it turns out, DER is only one possible encoding. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One#Packed_Encoding_Rules), there is also PER (with variants UPER and APER). I downloaded a few samples, and it seems that we could save about 40-45% of bytes, provided the reader of the certificate knows the ASN.1 schema (we could manage this in our case). This would be enough to make a QR Code scannable again.

However, I cannot find a way to convert DER to PER. Does anybody know how this can be done?

Or has anyone a better idea how we could transport the X.509 certificate to the phone of a user without offering them at a central repository?

Comment: Certificates in QR codes sounds like a little bit of a security issue for me, especially if you want to use phones around: it will be very easy to make a photo of a certificate.

Comment: Yes, but aren't certificates supposed to be public? Every website shows its certificate to me, so that I can determine if it is valid. Or am I not seeing something?

Answer (score 3):

Find an ASN.1 tool that supports both DER and PER. Using that tool, write a little program that decodes the DER-encoded value (i.e., the certificate) into an internal representation and then re-encodes it in PER.

Usually, PER Unaligned produces the most compact encodings, but I suggest you try both PER Unaligned and PER Aligned.